# How can I calculate this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{\sinh a k}{\sinh (\pi k) \sinh (\frac{\pi k}{2})}e^{ikx} $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I have the following integral as:
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d k \frac{\sinh a k}{\sinh (\pi k) \sinh (\frac{\pi k}{2})}e^{ikx} 
$$
where $0\leq a \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
Can any one help me calculataing this integral? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with contour integration?

Comment: Could $a \in (-3 \pi/2,3 \pi/2)$?

Comment: Not exactly, but the approach is the same (integration in the complex plane) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395822/integrate-int-0-infty-frac-sinh-ax-sinh-x-cos-bx-dx   or     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61605/tough-integral-involving-sinx2-and-sinh2-x

Comment: @RonGordon Yes it could be.

Comment: @MarkViola just a little bit, any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\sinh a k}{\sinh (\pi k) \sinh (\frac{\pi k}{2})}e^{ikx}dk=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\sinh a k}{2\sinh^2 (\frac{\pi k}{2}) \cosh (\frac{\pi k}{2})}e^{ikx}dk=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\sinh 2a k}{\sinh^2 (\pi k) \cosh (\pi k)}e^{2ikx}dk$$

For the convenience we will evaluate the integral

$$J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\sinh a k}{\sinh^2 (\pi k) \cosh (\pi k)}e^{ikx}dk=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{ikx}}{\sinh^2 (\pi k) \cosh (\pi k)}\Bigl(e^{ak}-e^{-ak}\Bigr)dk=\frac{1}{2}\bigr(I(a)-I(-a)\bigl)$$

We will consider $I(a)$ and $I(-a)$ separately. This is not rigorous, but we know that at $a \in (-3 \pi/2,3 \pi/2)$ integral is convergent, and we don't have singularity at $x\to0$: due to the symmetry only $i\sin(kx)$ survive from $e^{ikx}$, what gives additional power of $x$ at $x\to0$ and makes $x=0$ a removable singular point.
$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{ikx}}{\sinh^2 (\pi k) \cosh (\pi k)}e^{ak}dk$$

We choose the following contour in the complex plane:
[image]

To close the contour we also add two small half-circles ($C_1$ and $C_2$ above the point $x=0$ and below $x=i$ (we go counter clockwise in both cases) and vertical lines $1$ and $2$ at $R\to\pm\infty$

Integral along the closed contour looks
$$\oint =I(a)+\int_{C_1}+\int_1+\,\,e^{ia-x}I(a)+\int_{C_2}+\int_2=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{x=\frac{i}{2}}\biggl(\frac{e^{ikx}}{\sinh^2 (\pi k) \cosh (\pi k)}e^{ak}\biggr)$$

It can be shown that $\int_1$ and $\int_2\, \to0$ at $R\to\infty$. We have a single pole of first order inside the contour at $x=\frac{i}{2}$, so
$$I(a)(1+e^{ia-x})+\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}=-2\exp{(\frac{ia-x}{2})}$$

$$\int_{C_1}=\lim_{r\to0}\int_{-\pi}^0\frac{\exp{(are^{i\phi})}\exp{(ix re^{i\phi})}}{\bigl(\pi re^{i\phi}+\frac{(\pi re^{i\phi})^3}{3!}+...\bigr)^2}ire^{i\phi}d\phi=\lim_{r\to0}\int_{-\pi}^0\frac{1+re^{i\phi}(a+ix)+ O(r^2)}{\bigl(\pi re^{i\phi}+\frac{(\pi re^{i\phi})^3}{3!}+...\bigr)^2}ire^{i\phi}d\phi$$

Integral contains the divergent term, but it does not depend on $a$, so it will be canceled when we evaluate $I(a)-I(-a)$ - as it should be.
Keeping only converging terms we get:
$$\int_{C_1}=-\frac{i}{\pi} (a+ix)$$

In the same fashion we get
$$\int_{C_2}=\frac{i}{\pi} (a+ix)e^{ia-x}$$

Taking all together
$$I(a)=\frac{i}{\pi}\,(a+ix)\frac{1-e^{ia-x}}{1+e^{ia-x}}-2\frac{e^{\frac{ia-x}{2}}}{1+e^{ia-x}}$$
$$I(a)-I(-a)=\frac{2ia}{\pi}\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x+\cos a}+\frac{2 ix}{\pi}\frac{\sin a}{\cosh x+\cos a}-4i\frac{\sin\frac{a}{2}\sinh \frac{x}{2}}{\cosh x+\cos a}$$

Taking one half and switching to the initial $a$ and $x$ ($a\to 2a$ and $x\to 2x$)
$$J=\frac{2i}{\pi}\,\frac{a\sinh 2x+x\sin 2a-\pi\sin a\sinh x}{\cosh 2x+\cos 2a}$$

Please check the calculations.

Comment: Just corrected several typos (lost $\frac{1}{\pi^2}$ in the first term - $\sinh^2\pi x=(\pi x)^2+...$ at $x\to0\,$)

Comment: First of all thank you very much @Svyatoslav for your detailed answer. I guess a minus sign is lost on the way $2\pi i Res_{x=\frac{i}{2}}=2\pi i (\frac{i}{\pi}e^{\frac{1}{2}(i a-x)})=-2e^{\frac{1}{2}(i a-x)}$. I think also that there is an extra pre-factor of 1/2 in the second definition of I(a) (just before the the contour plot ). By divergent term you mean : $\frac{i}{\pi^{2}r e^{i\phi}}$ ? Finally, I am having slightly different pre-factors in the final result. Your answer was very helpful for me ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you. This is good that you checked the result - I did only quick check ($I=0$ at $k=0$ and $a=0$). You are right: the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ just before the contour plot is extra (but, luckily, it is not used in the further calculations :) - I will remove it from the text. Divergent term - also correct. You are also right regarding the residual at $x=\frac{i}{2}$: $\,\sinh^2(\pi i/2)=-\sin^2(\pi/2)$ - I lost this sign. Sorry for these mistakes. Such calculations require attention and thoroughness...

Comment: Dear @Svyatoslav this is what I got as a final result : $\frac{i}{\pi} \frac{(2x-\pi)\sin(2a)+2a\sinh(2x)}{\cos(2a)+\cosh(2x)}$ and I hope I am not mistaken.

Comment: I'm afraid $I(x\to0)\to0$ - because of the symmetry (in fact we integrate $\sin kx$ from $e^{ikx}=\cos k x+i\sin kx$ in the nominator - integral with $\cos k x$ - wanish).

Comment: Another point is the change $x\to-ia$ and $a\to ix$ - integral should not change (due to $\sinh ka\sin kx\to \sin kx\sinh ka$)

Comment: if the solution has the term $\sin a\sinh x$ - these requirements are met.

Comment: Dear @Svyatoslav, your arguments are corrects. I checked again and your final expression is correct. I do not know how but I lost the factor 1/2 in the Res. on the way. I am sorry for the mistake and thank you again!

Comment: @HJames You did a great job. Now you can easily evaluate this type of integrals. Good luck!